# Do U.S. Domestic Flights Allow Carrying Meat Inboard?

Tags: usa, hand-luggage, domestic-travel, prohibited-items

This might be a weird question but I hope you have an answer.

Are the U.S. domestic flights have restriction in carrying raw meat (such as ground beef, boneless chicken) in the cabin?  I mean, is raw meat considered to be prohibited to carry it in?

Comment: How would you transport it so it doesn't spoil?

Comment: @Karlson I keep it frozen in a small foam box.

Comment: This really isn't that weird -- just imagine someone coming back from an Alaskan hunting trip with a foam cooler full o' elk or w/e on ice. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually may not be an [TSA](http://www.tsa.gov) policy but an airline one.  An article in [AZ central](http://getawaytips.azcentral.com/frozen-meat-airplane-3245.html) suggests that not all airline allow frozen meats in carry-ons so you may need to check with the airline that they do.

The same article also suggests possible packing tips for transporting the frozen meats as well.

Personally I would suggest having your meat vacuum packed before freezing it.